# How to return the result in a recursive permutation function in R?

Tags: r, recursion

folk,
I am quite new to coding and R.
I am practicing writing a permutation function in R, and this this function was supposed to return all possibilities of rearrangement elements in a given vector. Here is my code:

"

```
result<-data.frame()
counts<-0
swap<-function(arrx,a,b){p1=arrx[a];p2=arrx[b];arrx[a]=p2;arrx[b]=p1;return(arrx)}
permu<-function(arrx,k){
  m=length(arrx)
  
  if (k==m)
  {cat(arrx,"\n");counts=counts+1;result<-rbind(result,arrx)}
  else {for (i in k:m){
   arrx<- swap(arrx,i,k)
   permu(arrx,k+1)
   arrx<- swap(arrx,i,k)

  }}
  return(list(result,counts))}
permu(c("a","b","c"),1)
```

"
after running it in R studio, I got this:
"

```
> permu(c("a","b","c"),1)
a b c 
a c b 
b a c 
b c a 
c b a 
c a b 
[[1]]
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

[[2]]
[1] 0
```

"
it seems that it can do the recursive permute job correctly. However, it cannot save the result in a dataframe via "return()". I googled a bit and found that in python there is a function called "yield", but in R, I cannot figure this out.
How should I save the results in the way I want in R?

Comment: I don't see any assignment of the result to an object name.

Comment: Hello IRTFM, Thank  you for your answer. I have "result<-rbind(result,arrx)" at the end of branch when each recursion is solved. Would you please provide suggestions on how to modify this?

Answer (score 0):

You assigned the value of `result`which was an empty data.frame to the first item in a list and the value of counts which was a length one numeric vector with value 0 (both obtained from the global environment. You did nothing with the `arrx` object so it was garbage collected. It also looks like you might have intended to have the `rbind` operation and the "incremetation" of `counts` to occur inside the loop. At the moment there doesn't appear to be any storage of "results" in `result`.

R is not great at recursion. If you want to learn how it is supported you can look at the `?Recall` help page.

Comment: ```swap<-function(arrx,a,b){p1=arrx[a];p2=arrx[b];arrx[a]=p2;arrx[b]=p1;return(arrx)}
result<-data.frame()
counts<-0
permu<-function(arrx,k){
  m=length(arrx)
  
  if (k==m)
  {cat(arrx,"\n")}
  else {for (i in k:m){
  
   arrx<- swap(arrx,i,k)
   permu(arrx,k+1)
   counts=counts+1;result<-rbind(result,arrx)
   arrx<- swap(arrx,i,k)
  }}
  return(list(result,counts))}
permu(c("a","b","c"),1)```  I change the code to this, but still get a 3-row dataframe as the returned result and counts=3. What is the essence to the problem?